# How to assign value to a variable name which is another variable in groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

Suppose I have this:

```
name = "some_name" 
address = "some_value"
```

and I want to assign value of address variable to value of name variable like below:

```
some_name = "some_value"
```

so, that when I do some thing like

```
this is "${some_name}"
```

It should print

> this is some_value

I am going this as I need to expose key, value pair of maps(which we get as input from user) as variable so that it would be accessible to Jenkins build.

I tried:

```
"${name}" = "${value}"
```

But it throws error.

Is there any way in Groovy, I could achieve this?

Comment: what hinders you to use a plain `Map` and access its key/values the standard way? The you should be able to expose this map to anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I have to say this is an odd use case. Maybe theres a better way to solve your problem if elaborate a little more, but in any case this should work for what you are asking.

```
def name = "some_name"
def address = "some_value"

def myMap = [:]

myMap["${name}"] = address

println "this is ${myMap.some_name}"
```

Output:

```
this is some_value
```